# NIToolBarPhotoViewController to display images from a selected image

Tags: image-gallery, photo-gallery, nimbus, nimbus-ios, photoviewer

I am using Nimbus to display photos. I have a tableviewcontroller displaying list of filenames. When the user select particular file (if an image) , it displays all the image files in viewcontroller extended from NIToolBarPhotoViewController starting fromt the first element of my photo source array i.e. photoFiles which is the first element in list.

I am returning the total count for scrollview pages like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfPagesInPagingScrollView:(NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoScrollView {
    return self.photoFiles.count;
}
```

However, I am unable to launch the photoview from a particular index as the method:

```
  - (UIImage *)photoAlbumScrollView: (NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoAlbumScrollView
                     photoAtIndex: (NSInteger)photoIndex
                        photoSize: (NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSize *)photoSize
                        isLoading: (BOOL *)isLoading
          originalPhotoDimensions: (CGSize *)originalPhotoDimensions
```

gets called directly as per the example NetworkPhotoAlbumViewController. How can I get it to take the particular index before launch the photoview?

Comment: Found the method : 'setCenterPageIndex' in NIPageScrollView . Since NiPhotoAlbumScrollView is child class of this class. We can set the property there directly.

Comment: This is the correct way to change the page from code.

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad add this line

```
[self.photoAlbumView setCenterPageIndex:photoIndex];
```

to set index of displayed photo